# Easiest way to upload existing data in to new database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, deployment

First apologize me if am posting my question in a wrong forum.

We have implemented our old software(Java swing application) in a school 3 yrs before.

Now we are planning to install our new software(Java spring MVC web application). Already they had entered manually more than 3000+ students record when we implement first time. Now again they cant enter the same data in our new system... Is there any way to translate the existing record to our new database.. How to achieve this...

---edited---
Database varies for two application.

for eg:

I have 15 fields extra in my new dabase... also all my column names are changed.

Please guide me..

Comment: Are you changing your database ?  Migrating the application from `swing` to web has no effect on the database part.If you are trying to migrate the database . Please post the database details

Comment: Down voters please post the reason..... Dont discourage the users...

Comment: When the users are not aware 100% skilled and seeking help from the experts who are all in that particular domains.. But sorry to say this your responses really discourage me...  Everyone will give their best when they are really in need....

Answer (score 1):

You can write down some code that connect on the old database, read the data and create and insert on the newer database. Based on information about your DBMS I can suggest you this approach. First make your software run this SQL statement:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE t\G
```

With this, you can get the database information, so you can create the same database on the new server. Then with all fields in hand, you can run a select statement to get all the rows and store them as strings on a list, so you can run them later on the other database. Another way is to simply run mysqldump like this:

```
mysqldump -t -u MyUserName -MyPassword MyDatabase MyTable
```

Assuming that you don't have direct access to mysqldump, and by the way, writing down this piece of code is fairly easy, I will stick with the show create table plus select insert. And just to explain my select that generates the insert, is just like that:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE t\G

Create Table: CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT(11) default NULL auto_increment,
  s char(60) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM

"SELECT 'INSERT INTO t(id,s) VALUES(' as inserthead,id,',\'' as firstcomma,s,'')' as endofstatement from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's impossible to answer your question. You haven't given any information how the data is stored in the old system (flat files, relational database, other database type), what you are using in the new one, what is the structure of the information stored in the first app, is it similar to the one used in the latter, etc. There is a world of details required to give you a hint, and your question gives nothing of these.

Comment: am using mysql database.. have to transfer data from one database to another database..